# Animation fade | jQuery vs pure js | setInterval vs. setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this tested function below that works fine for fading an element in or out.

What do I gain by using JQuery?

Thanks

```
Effects.prototype.fade = function( direction, max_time,  element ) 
{
    var elapsed = 0;
    function next() {
        elapsed += 10;
        if (direction === 'up')
        {
            element.style.opacity = elapsed / max_time;
        }
        else if (direction === 'down')
        {
            element.style.opacity = (max_time - elapsed) / max_time;
        }
        if (elapsed <= max_time) {
            setTimeout(next, 10);
        }
    }
    next();
};
```

Running a search on fadeIn() on the core jquery library I get one hit here:

```
jQuery.each({
    slideDown: genFx( "show", 1 ),
    slideUp: genFx( "hide", 1 ),
    slideToggle: genFx( "toggle", 1 ),
    fadeIn: { opacity: "show" },
    fadeOut: { opacity: "hide" },
    fadeToggle: { opacity: "toggle" }
}, function( name, props ) {
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( speed, easing, callback ) {
        return this.animate( props, speed, easing, callback );
    };
});
```

Using the [JQuery Source Viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=animate)

```
function (prop, speed, easing, callback) {
    var optall = jQuery.speed(speed, easing, callback);
    if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(prop)) {
        return this.each(optall.complete, [false]);
    }
    prop = jQuery.extend({},
    prop);
    return this[optall.queue === false ? "each" : "queue"](function () {
        if (optall.queue === false) {
            jQuery._mark(this);
        }
        var opt = jQuery.extend({},
        optall),
            isElement = this.nodeType === 1,
            hidden = isElement && jQuery(this).is(":hidden"),
            name, val, p, display, e, parts, start, end, unit;
        opt.animatedProperties = {};
        for (p in prop) {
            name = jQuery.camelCase(p);
            if (p !== name) {
                prop[name] = prop[p];
                delete prop[p];
            }
            val = prop[name];
            if (jQuery.isArray(val)) {
                opt.animatedProperties[name] = val[1];
                val = prop[name] = val[0];
            } else {
                opt.animatedProperties[name] = opt.specialEasing && opt.specialEasing[name] || opt.easing || "swing";
            }
            if (val === "hide" && hidden || val === "show" && !hidden) {
                return opt.complete.call(this);
            }
            if (isElement && (name === "height" || name === "width")) {
                opt.overflow = [this.style.overflow, this.style.overflowX, this.style.overflowY];
                if (jQuery.css(this, "display") === "inline" && jQuery.css(this, "float") === "none") {
                    if (!jQuery.support.inlineBlockNeedsLayout) {
                        this.style.display = "inline-block";
                    } else {
                        display = defaultDisplay(this.nodeName);
                        if (display === "inline") {
                            this.style.display = "inline-block";
                        } else {
                            this.style.display = "inline";
                            this.style.zoom = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (opt.overflow != null) {
            this.style.overflow = "hidden";
        }
        for (p in prop) {
            e = new jQuery.fx(this, opt, p);
            val = prop[p];
            if (rfxtypes.test(val)) {
                e[val === "toggle" ? hidden ? "show" : "hide" : val]();
            } else {
                parts = rfxnum.exec(val);
                start = e.cur();
                if (parts) {
                    end = parseFloat(parts[2]);
                    unit = parts[3] || (jQuery.cssNumber[p] ? "" : "px");
                    if (unit !== "px") {
                        jQuery.style(this, p, (end || 1) + unit);
                        start = (end || 1) / e.cur() * start;
                        jQuery.style(this, p, start + unit);
                    }
                    if (parts[1]) {
                        end = (parts[1] === "-=" ? -1 : 1) * end + start;
                    }
                    e.custom(start, end, unit);
                } else {
                    e.custom(start, val, "");
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: 1. You don't have to write it. 2. You don't have to write it. 3. You don't have to... well :) Consider that "writing it" also implies "accounting for browser quirks". It also nicely fits into the rest of the jQuery effect model for chaining, etc.

Comment: Just download the jQuery developer source and extract the fadeIn function. jQuery's fadeIn does something similar to your function but it performs better under load, trying to keep to timing constraints. Also, the entire animate library is quite well designed and stuff just works.

Comment: from what i observed before, jQuery uses timers (setTimeout) to recursively call the function. that way, your UI won't lock-up during the transitioning.

Comment: @Joseph - that's what I do to...where can I find the JQuery implementation?

Comment: The code shows that `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` and others are handled via `this.animate`.

Comment: If you're ever interested in seeing the jQuery source for a function, look at James Padolsey's jQuery source viewer: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.fn.fadeIn

Comment: **@Guy Montag** the function is `animate()` that runs in the callback and takes care of most things. If you're using jQuery already there's no reason to reinvent the wheel, use the function that it provides.

Comment: Take a look at CSS transitions... no need to write any JS or include monstrosities like the above. Degrades gracefully.

Comment: `setInterval` alone should be reason to cast suspicion on the legitimacy of the code. http://blog.propcom.co.uk/technology/setinterval-vs-recursive-settimeout-pattern

Comment: @GuyMontag I'm pretty sure 10 has transitions. Anyway, is the effect vital to the purpose of the page, or is it eye candy? If it's eye candy, consider browsers that don't support it to be gracefully degrading ;)

Comment: @JQuery...you are not following you own coding style as reported here http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines

Comment: @GuyMontag if you're really looking for a reason to ditch jQuery, just run some performance tests. You don't even have to write them yourself, just google, for example, "jsperf jquery css"

Comment: +1 for actually looking at and evaluating the code you are considering using in your project, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you don't include a library like [**jQuery**](http://api.jquery.com/) just for a single effect, but as a general purpose library in order to simplify things such as DOM [manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/), [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) calls, setting [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/) properties in a way that's cross-browser, in addition to applying [effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) (such as `.fadeIn`/`.fadeOut`) and [other](http://api.jquery.com/category/data/) [applications](http://api.jquery.com/category/miscellaneous/).

Tipically it's recommended you don't add jQuery for just a simple call. But my reasoning is that you are probably be going to exploit more and more of it's features in the long run, so I don't see a real reason not to use it.

On the subject of implementing your own fadeIn or fadeOut functions, you could look at the [jQuery source](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js) and extract those methods, or make your own implementation from scratch. But given the fact that jQuery already implemented this method, I don't see why you would want to replicate it, other than for educational purposes.

Comment: You can't extract from jQuery - look at the source above and how many ways it branches...it is not modular.

Comment: well, you could get the idea from it.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest reason to use JQuery over your custom code, in my opinion, is that you don't have to maintain the code for multiple browsers and multiple versions.  JQuery does a good job of handling the quirks of the major browsers for you.

In addition, there are many other excellent uses for JQuery that you may want to use later.

Concerning the code, when you download JQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery  you can get the uncompressed version, which is intended to be readable.

I don't know of a simple way to get only those functions out of JQuery.  Why not use the full library?